# Finding all possible pairs of positive integer values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

The ratio of the sum of two positive integers to their difference is $7:5$. If the the sum of the two numbers is at most $25$, find all possible values for the pair of numbers.

Let $m$ be the first positive integer.

Then $\frac{m}{6}$ is the second positive integer.

This gives $m = 21.4$, but now I'm stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $x\geq y$ We have it that 
$$
5(x+y)=7(x-y)
$$

and that $x+y\leq25$

Continuing with the above equality we get 
$$
5x+5y=7x-7y
$$

$$
2x=12y
$$
$$
x=6y
$$

hence the solutions are $(1,6),(2,12),(3,18)$

Comment: Because I can assume without loss of generality that x>=y (otherwise y>=x and we change their names ). I have used this in the first equation, the LHS is positive and by that assumption the RHS is also positive